# Constructing json object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am facing issues while constructing an object using javascript. I want this:

```
{
    "p_id": "2",
    "p_name": "weblogic",
    "ip_list": [
        {
            "ip_id": 2690
        },
        {
            "ip_id": 2692
        },
        {
            "ip_id": 2693
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the javascript code that I am using to get the data into the object:

```
var ipArray = [];
secTagJSON.p_name = "weblogic";
secTagJSON.p_id = "2";
for (var index=0; index < selectedArray.length; index++){
    secTagJSON.ip_list.push("ip_id": selectedArray[index]);
}
```

I am able to construct the properties for p_id and p_name but struggling to create the the ip_list. Please let me know how to get this constructed using javascript.

Code for posting to the server:

```
var ipArray = [];
secTagJSON.p_name = "weblogic";
secTagJSON.p_id = 2;
for (var index=0; index < selectedArray.length; index++){
 secTagJSON.ip_list.push({"ip_id": selectedArray[index]});
}
console.log (secTagJSON);
console.log (JSON.stringify(secTagJSON));
 $http.post("http://server:port/api/v1/tags").
    success(function(data) {
      console.log (data)
    });
```

Comment: What you just posted is a valid way to construct it using Javascript.

Comment: Hmmm . What you mean by constructing ? ... because i suspect that something is terribly wrong by your words

Comment: How are you *creating* the json?

Comment: Please find the below code that I have written to construct the json message:

   var ipArray = [];
    secTagJSON.p_name = "weblogic";
    secTagJSON.p_id = "2";
    for (var index=0; index < selectedArray.length; index++){
     secTagJSON.ip_list.push("ip_id": selectedArray[index]);
    }

 But I am not getting in the desired format as mentioned in my question

Comment: Remove comma after every set in ip_list and it will become valid JSON according to jsonlint.com

Comment: That is my expected json. But how do I construct the json using javascript language?

Comment: What are `secTagJSON` and `selectedArray`? Why arent' you using `ipArray`?

Comment: FWIW, JavaScript is not JSON and vice-versa. Nothing in your post is JSON--it's all JavaScript.

Comment: @JAAulde made a simple but important observation.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
secTagJSON.p_name = "weblogic";
secTagJSON.p_id = "2";
secTagJSON.ip_list = [];
for (var index=0; index < selectedArray.length; index++){
 secTagJSON.ip_list.push({"ip_id": selectedArray[index]});
}
```

you forgot your {} around "ip_id": etc...
You also need to declare that ip_list is an array.
Your `ip_list` is an array of objects.  I would guess that your script was not running as it was.

Posting to your server you should use:

`$http.post('server:port/api/v1/tags', secTagJSON).sucess(...`

Comment: Thanks. It worked but when I am trying to post the json I am getting 415 error - 415 (Unsupported Media Type). Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have added the code to post to the server in my question. I am using AngularJs for http post calls.

Comment: @user883561 It looks like you're not actually sending the data... so the content type is not getting set by i'm guessing Angular...  try $http.post('http://server:port/api/v1/tags', secTagJSON).sucess(...

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
var obj = { ip_list: [] };

obj.p_name = "weblogic";
obj.p_id = "2";

for (var i = 0, j = selectedArray.length; i < j; i++)
   obj.ip_list.push({ ip_id: selectedArray[i] });
```

Note that your `ip_list` is actually an array of objects. So, when you iterate over it, remember that each `var item = json.ip_list[i]` will return an object, that you can access its properties using: `item['ip_id']`.

Note that `obj` is an Javascript object, it is not an JSON. If you want the JSON, you can use `JSON.stringify(obj)`. This will return your JSON (string).

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Yes. I got it working now but when I am trying to post the json to the server, I am getting 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error. Could you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: How are you sending it? Did you set the contentType? And if you did, is your server expecting JSON format? I edited my answer telling you that if you wnat to send the JSON, you need to serialize your javascript object.